# Fill parent in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `HStack` with 2 `Text` and I need each `Text` to adapt to its brother's height, I tried `.scaledToFill()` but it's not working

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        return HStack {
            Text("test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test ")
                .background(Color.red)
            Text("test test test test test")
                .scaledToFill()
                .background(Color.red)
        }.background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

The result: 
[image]

The desired result :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply equal .frame() modifier

```
var body: some View {
        HStack {
                Text("test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test ")
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.red)
                Text("test test test test test")
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.red)
        }.background(Color.blue)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: In this case the views will have a fixed size (`.infinity `), but I need the Text's frame adapt to the content size "test test test test...."